# Selenium run on alpine 3.6 container

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, alpine-linux

I'm trying to run `Selenium` on `alpine 3.6` container `(FROM alpine:3.6)`.

What I'm trying in container shell:

```
apk update
apk add python3
pip3 install -U selenium
apk add chromium
apk add chromium-driver
```

And running the following python (using python3):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'usr/bin/chromedriver') # Thrown an exception
```

And got the following exception:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 5.0.0-23-generic x86_64)

```
selenium=3.141.0
chromium=57.0.2987.133
chromeDriver=2.27
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please post some more info like chrome browser version and selenium version as well.Seems like this is a compatible issue you need to have compatible version of webdriver.you can see following link to check which chrome driver supports the  chrome version https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @KunduK, see my edit with selenium, chromium versions

Comment: I would suggest you to upgrade both chrome driver and browser to latest version.This seems very old version you are using.I haven’t work on that platform so don’t know how to upgrade.however you might know how to upgrade and see if you can crack that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by the followings steps (Work with alpine3.6):

Update the repositores:

```
echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" > /etc/apk/repositories
echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

Apk Update:

```
apk update
```

Install chromium & chromedriver:

```
apk add chromium
apk add chromium-chromedriver
```

Install python3, selenium:

```
apk add python3
pip3 install -U selenium
```

And the following `python` code works for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://example.com')
```

Comment: "Install chromium & chromedriver" --> solved all strange random errors that I had.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I did to get selenium to work with alpine3.9 and firefox, hopefull this is helpful

took me a long time to figure out the perfect versions

geckodriver must be version 0.21.0

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine3.9
RUN apk update
RUN apk add firefox-esr
RUN apk add xvfb
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

## requirements.txt

```
selenium==3.11
pyvirtualdisplay==0.2.1
```

## python code

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: you will need 0.21.0 I think https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.21.0, and you are using pyvirtualdisplay?

Comment: you need to specify the path for it, you can do that with this argument `executable_path=GECKO_DRIVER_PATH` in the webdriver.Firefox call with GECKOD_DRIVER_PATH being a string

Comment: did this work for you? if so mark the answer as correct